# Array, Get value and set in Variable

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a set of JavaScript arrays which are rendered dynamically. I want to get the data from the array one by one and want to assign that value to a variable.

**Here is my JavaScript code**

```
var count;

for (count = 0; count <= employee_yearly_sales.length; ++count) {
  var d2 = employee_yearly_sales[count];
  console.log(d2);
}

var d1 = [[id, roundoff]]; // Here value come dynamically 
var d2 = [[id, roundoff]]; // Here value come dynamically 

  var data1 = [
  {label: created_by,  data: d1} // Here value come dynamically for title
  {label: created_by,  data: d2} // Here value come dynamically for title
];
```

**Array Output**

```
    [Object]
    0: Object
        created_by: "1"
        id: "9"
        roundoff: "0.00"
        updated_at: "2014-11-13 10:33:46"
[Object]
    0: Object
        created_by: "2"
        id: "106"
        roundoff: "0.00"
        updated_at: "2014-11-13 10:33:46"
```

[image]

How can I add values to a variable? Thanks.

**Here is PHP code, From where data come**

```
public function EmployeeYearlySales() {

$data = array();

$res = $this->db->query("SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM employees");
$result = $res->fetchAll(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);

foreach ($result as $item => $items) {
$order = $this->db->query("SELECT distinct id, SUM(roundoff) AS         roundoff,updated_at,created_by FROM orders WHERE created_by = " . $items['id']);
$order_result = $order->fetchAll(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
$data[] = $order_result;
}

var_dump($data);
//exit;

if ($result) {
  return $result;
  echo json_encode($result);
}
else
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate to what you are trying to accomplish?  Is array output what you're getting from the server ?  Are trying to add another record of data or you're trying to add another attribute of data?

Comment: @josephnvu I want to add array data to variable d1 and data1 dynamically

Comment: Even with the latest comment this question remains unclear. How is the dynamic code loaded, are you using Ajax? Or something else?

Comment: @Mouser Question Updated. please check

Comment: @josephnvu Question Updated. please check

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. It build the array dynamically from the data in your retrieved SQL data. In the for lus it pushed the label value with the `created_by` data and sets a `data` property containing an *array* with the `id` and `roundoff`. I deducted this from your question. I hope that this is what you were searching for.

```
var count;
var data = [];

for (count = 0; count <= employee_yearly_sales.length; ++count) {
  var dataObj = employee_yearly_sales[count];

  data.push( {label: dataObj[0],  data: [dataObj[1], dataObj[2]]} );// Here value come dynamically for title
}

console.log(data);
```

```
This will create:
[Array]
0: [Object]
    label: 1
    data: [Array]
        0: 9
        1: "0.00"
1: [Object]
    label: 2
    data: [Array]
        0: 106
        1: "0.00"
```